# how to upload any file and save it to a specfic folder in spring mvc

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a dialog box from where I have given a option to upload a file but its not working. I mean request in not going to controller. my code is shown below: 
My JSP Div content:

Content of dialog Box is :

```
<form method="post" action="fileUploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    Please select a file to upload :<input type="file" name="fileUpload"  id="Uploadfile"/>
<input type="submit" value="Upload" onclick="Uploadfiles();"/>

    </form>
```

Java Script function:
Now how i have to use form data to send this request to controller and again i should get  a string response in success like uploaded succesfully. I have tried like this but its not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Uploadfiles(){
$('#result').html('');
var formdata=document.getElementById("Uploadfile"); 
var fd = new FormData(formdata);
fd.append("CustomField","This is an additional data");

$.ajax({
    url: contextPath +"/fileUploadForm",
    dataType: 'text',
    data: fd,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false, 
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data){
            alert("inside success ***");
            $('#result').html(data);

    } ,
    error: function(){
        alert("error has occured");

        }
});
}
</script>
```

Because i am not sure what should be the controller code as i got it from a site. if i use what i have mention here i am getting error like incorrect syntax i mean the data send by ajax call to  controller is not correct syntactically to accept the form data i.e. so problem with what ajax call is sending and what controller code is expecting. Pls let me know what should be the correct way to implement how to send a file request in ajax call so the controller should get proper data. As saving file code is working fine if i will not use this ajax call files are getting saved properly.
Now my controller code:

```
   private static final String KDC_FILE_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER = "/root/Desktop/Upload_Files/";

  @RequestMapping(value= "/fileUploadForm",method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String handleFileUpload(HttpServletRequest request,
        @RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile[] fileUpload) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("finally in controller ");

    if (fileUpload != null && fileUpload.length > 0) {
        for (CommonsMultipartFile aFile : fileUpload){

            System.out.println("Saving file: " + aFile.getOriginalFilename());

            if (!aFile.getOriginalFilename().equals("")) {
                aFile.transferTo(new File(FILE_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER + aFile.getOriginalFilename()));
            }
        }
    }

    // returns to the view "Result"
    return "File has been Uploaded Successfully";
}
```

Changes in my spring Dispatcher servlet xml file is: 
i have added below line only as to use multipart

```
 <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>
```

Please let me know what is wrong in my code and if we can achieve the same results using some other approach.

Spring dispatcher servlet file :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop/spring-hadoop.xsd">

<bean id="userController" class="com.controller.UserLoginController">
 <property name="multipartResolver" ref="multipartResolver"></property>

</bean>
 <bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <!-- max upload size in bytes -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="20971520" /> <!-- 20MB -->

    <!-- max size of file in memory (in bytes) -->
    <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="1048576" /> <!-- 1MB -->

</bean>
```

Comment: How do you get contextpath? and is your web.xml configured correctly ?

Comment: yes i am getting context path like this <c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" /> and <script type="text/javascript">
     var contexPath = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>";
 </script>

Comment: you used the variable as contexPath, with a missing t inside ajax call, can that be the problem ?

Comment: thanks Ozan for correcting me i have changed the typo done earlier now still request in not going to my controller i want only request should go to controller in controller code is working fine.

Comment: the controller not being called still seems like a contextpath problem to me, are you sure the page you try to upload gets the correct contextPath? can you post here the actual value set in your ajax call ?

Comment: Ozan just now to check contextpath i have done this: <script type="text/javascript">
function test(){
 
 $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: contextPath+"/test",
  dataType: 'text',
        success: function(){
    alert("inside success ***");
         
  } ,
  error: function(){
   alert("error has occured");
         
         }
 });
 
}</script>    Contoller code @RequestMapping(value= "/test",method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String test(){
  System.out.println("iside steing ");
  return "Hiii";
 } i can see the sysout comment although its going in error block but atleast controller invoked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66280/discussion-between-sanjay-and-ozan-tabak).

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for controller method is not being called is the parameter `FormDataMultiPart`,which is jersey file upload api. You are mixing this API with spring MVC.

I would suggest you to use `MultipartFile` API for the uploading purpose, like below.

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/fileUploadForm" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public @ResponseBody
String uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
   // your code...
}
```

Comment: so what you are getting now??

Comment: sorry,i am unable to understand your problem, do you mean is it the form in dialog box may cause problem?

Comment: And you said  your Spring API is correct now,as you have tested it with Standalone client?

Comment: yes if the form in dialog box can cause any porblem. and i have created sample spring mvc project i am able to upload files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66383/discussion-between-re350-and-sanjay).

Comment: RE350 if possible can u pls look now i have edited the question and its content. thanks in advance

Comment: can you post here your spring configuration file code?

Comment: i have posted my spring configuration file.

Comment: <context:component-scan base-package="your_controller_package" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

Comment: i suppose after adding these two lines to your Spring dispatcher servlet file, Spring mvc will start scanning your components.

Comment: i am not using mvc annotation driven as of now for all the beans i have bean and in controller bean as a property attribute i am refering that bean as well in controller i have respective setter method if its problem with the conf then i same project instead of ajax call through form submit file is getting saved but i my case i need to send this file using ajax call instead of form submit. so i boubt problem with parameter that controller expect and what ajax is sending may be

Comment: but still you will have to write <context:annotation-config /> also instaed of <mvc:annotation-driven/>..

Comment: did you test this after adding <context:annotation-config /> and <context:component-scan base-package="your_controller_package" /> ?

Comment: i have added this line in my controller <context:component-scan base-package="com.controller.UserLoginController" /> <context:annotation-config /> but still request is not going to controller

Comment: dude <context:component-scan base-package="com.controller.UserLoginController" /> should be <context:component-scan base-package="com.controller" />

Comment: or more specifically u can write,<context:component-scan base-package="com.controller.*" />

Comment: I am getting this error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot map handler [userLoginController] to URL path [/fileUploadForm]: There is already handler [com.controller.UserLoginController@2143c7dc] mapped. as of now i am using only one controller

Comment: just remove this line from your spring configuration file.<bean id="userController" class="com.controller.UserLoginController">..